# Thymeleaf: display global errors by error code

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

How can I display multiple global errors in my templates, by their respective error code?

When rejecting on the binding result, the first argument is the `error code`. How can I use this when displaying the errors in my template?

Use case: I use custom validation rules in my controller (such as duplication checks) and I want to show the global errors on different places in my form.

Ex:

```
public String myPage(..., BindingResult result) {
    result.reject("errorCode1", "Error 1 happened");
    result.reject("errorCode2", "Error 2 happened");
    return "my-view"
}
```

In my Thymeleaf template, I can display all errors at once:

```
<form th:object="${myForm}" method="post">
    <p th:if="${#fields.hasGlobalErrors()}" th:errors="*{global}"></p>
</form>
```

But how can I print **only** the error with error code `errorCode1`?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way to do that. I suggest you to create another field in your object (myForm) and assign the error in BindingResult with rejectValue. Then you can validate the error on template:

```
public String myPage(..., BindingResult result) {
    result.reject("errorCode1", "Global Error Happened");
    result.rejectValue("newField", "Error 2 happened");
    return "my-view"
}

<form th:object="${myForm}" method="post">
    <p th:if="${#fields.hasGlobalErrors()}" th:errors="*{global}"></p>
    <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('newField')}" th:errors="*{newField}"></p>
</form>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Daniel, how can I achieve the same effect as calling result.reject (global error) when in webflux?

Answer (score 0):

It took me a bit to figure out, but it works like this:

```
public String myPage(..., BindingResult result) {
    result.reject("errorCode1", "errorCode1");
    result.reject("errorCode2", "errorCode2");
    return "my-view"
}
```

**Important:** `errorCode1` must not be a key of a message source!

```
<form th:object="${myForm}" method="post">
    <p th:if="${#lists.contains(#fields.globalErrors(), &quot;errorCode1d&quot;)}" th:text="Error 1 happened"></p>
</form>
```

**Important:** Use `&quot;` to indicate the string.
`th:text` may contain a message key like `th:text="#{error.code1}"`