# How to display RequestParam errors in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I want to use a form **without** an object. How to display errors?

**Controller:**

```
@PostMapping(value="/submit")
public String doSubmit(@RequestParam("myParameter") String param, BindingResult bindingResult) {
   bindingResult.rejectValue("myParameter", "Oh nooo!!!!"); 
   return "html";
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<form th:action = "@{/submit}" method="post">
    <label for="myParameter" class="form-label">My Parameter</label>
    <input name="myParameter" class="form-control" type="text"/>
    <span class="text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('myParameter')}" th:errors="myParameter">Error</span>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

`th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('myParameter')}" th:errors="myParameter"` throws errors, cause "myParameter" is not known.

How to display the error, **without** using `th:object` in `<form>`

Comment: You will have to implement custom logic in that case. Mostly redirecting to the same page with a parameter in uri (e.g. `return "redirect:/form?err"`) and then displaying an alert conditionally (`<span style="color: #8b0000" th:if=${param.err}>Error!</span>`) does the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it with the help of this question [Thymeleaf: display global errors by error code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58394445/8345434)

```
@PostMapping(value="/submit")
public String doSubmit(@RequestParam("myParameter") String param, BindingResult bindingResult) {
   bindingResult.reject("myParameter", "myParameter"); 
   return "html";
}
```

**Important:** `myParameter` must not be a key of a message source!

```
<form th:action="@{/submit}" method="post">
    <label for="myParameter" class="form-label">My Parameter</label>
    <input name="myParameter" class="form-control" type="text"/>
    <span class="text-danger" th:if="${#lists.contains(#fields.globalErrors(), &quot;myParameter&quot;)}" th:text="An Error happened">Error</span>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

**Important:** Use `&quot;` to indicate the string. `th:text? may contain a message key like` th:text="#{error.code1}"`.